# Sections in text neither numbered nor formatted but correct in TOC

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I have a latex template from my department which doesn't display my sections and subsections properly. They appear correctly in the TOC but in the text, they are neither numbered nor bold nor formatted in any way, but preceded by "0em0em", which I checked is from the title spacing definition:

```
\RequirePackage{titlesec}

\titlespacing{\section}{0em}{14pt}{4pt}[0em]
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0em}{8pt}{-2pt}[0em]  
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0em}{8pt}{-2pt}[0em]  
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0em}{4pt}{0em}[0em]  
\titlespacing{\subparagraph}{0em}{4pt}{0em}[0em]
```

So instead of **1.1 Introduction**

I'd get 0em0emIntroduction

Chapters work fine.

I hope that's enough info.

Cheers

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try deleting all the `\titlespacing` commands.

Comment: Hey Peter, it worked!

Comment: Thank you so much! Hope you have a nice day :)